# Most efficient way of creating a grid in HTML with CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to create a grid that in each cell there should be a 0 or a 1. These cells when clicked should toggle between 0 and 1. When hovered it should show the coordinates (e.g. 1,5).

Now the only way I got this to work was by creating three divs. One for the cell (which contains the number), one for the coordinates (this one is added dynamically) and another div (wrapper) that will on top of the other two and this one will have the event listeners.

So I'm creating three divs for cell, now this work perfectly if it's for a 10x10 grid, but when it gets to a more large (64x64) the browser starts to freeze.

This is how the HTML looks for a cell of the grid:

```
<div class="cell cellUnselected" id="cell_1_1" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">0</div>
<div class="cellCoordinates cellCoordText" id="cell_1_1_coord" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div>
<div class="cellWrapper" id="cell_1_1_wrapper" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div>
```

I created a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vicgonzalez25/Tfs2M/

The problem: Once the grid start getting to a bigger size (e.g. 64x64) by creating these three divs the browser starts to freeze. Is there a more efficient way of doing this grid?

Grid HTML:

```
<div id="grid" class="gridContainer">
    <div class="cell cellUnselected" id="cell_1_1" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">0</div>
    <div class="cellCoordinates cellCoordText" id="cell_1_1_coord" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div>
    <div class="cellWrapper" id="cell_1_1_wrapper" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div>
    <div class="cell cellUnselected" id="cell_1_2" style="left: 36px; top: 0px;">0</div>
    <div class="cellCoordinates cellCoordText" id="cell_1_2_coord" style="left: 36px; top: 0px;"></div>
    <div class="cellWrapper" id="cell_1_2_wrapper" style="left: 36px; top: 0px;"></div>
</div>
```

In order to reproduce:

HTML:

```
<div id="gridLayout" class="gridLayout">
    <div id="gridHeader">
        <h2>Aperture Configuration:</h2>
        Grid Size:
        <input id="rows" type="number" min="1" max="50" value="10" width="40" size="3" onChange="GRASP.start();">
        x
        <input id="cols" type="number" min="1" max="50" value="10" width="40" size="3" onChange="GRASP.start();">
    </div>
    <div id="grid" class="gridContainer"></div>

    <div id="matrixHeader" style="position:absolute">
        <h2>Auto Correlation:</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="matrix" class="autocorrMatrixContainer"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
(function(GRASP, $){
    var GRID_ROWS,
        GRID_COLS,
        GRID_ELEMENT,
        MATRIX_ROWS,
        MATRIX_COLS,
        MATRIXHEADER_ELEMENT,
        MATRIX_ELEMENT,
        A,C;

    GRASP.config = {
        gridContainer: "grid",
        matrixContainer: "matrix",
        matrixHeader: "matrixHeader"
    };

    GRASP.start = function(){
        GRID_ROWS = $("#rows").val();
        GRID_COLS = $("#cols").val();
        MATRIX_ROWS = GRID_ROWS * 2 - 1;
        MATRIX_COLS = GRID_COLS * 2 - 1;
        createGrid();
        createAutocorrelationMatrix();
    };

    function createGrid()
    {
        GRID_ELEMENT = $("#"+GRASP.config.gridContainer);
        GRID_ELEMENT.html(""); // Clear Grid ;)
        var coord;
        var cell; // Contains the 1 or 0 based upon the cell selection

        for(var i=1; i<=GRID_ROWS; i++){
            for(var j=1; j<=GRID_COLS; j++){
                coord = "" + i + "," + j;

                $(document.createElement("div"))
                    .addClass("cellWrapper")
                    .attr("alt", coord)
                    .css("left", parseInt((j-1) * 36, 10) + "px")
                    .css("top", parseInt((i-1) * 36, 10) + "px")
                    .width(36).height(36)
                    .data("row", i).data("col", j)
                    .appendTo("#"+GRASP.config.gridContainer)
                    .on("click", cellClick)
                    .on("mouseenter", {isMatrix: false}, cellMouseEnter)
                    .on("mouseleave", cellMouseLeave);

                $(document.createElement("div"))
                    .addClass("cell cellUnselected")
                    .attr("alt", coord)
                    .css("left", parseInt((j-1) * 36, 10) + "px")
                    .css("top", parseInt((i-1) * 36, 10) + "px")
                    .text("0")
                    .appendTo("#"+GRASP.config.gridContainer);
            }
        }

        GRID_ELEMENT.height(36 * GRID_ROWS);
        GRID_ELEMENT.width(36 * GRID_COLS);

    }

    function createAutocorrelationMatrix() {
        MATRIXHEADER_ELEMENT = $("#" + GRASP.config.matrixHeader);
        MATRIX_ELEMENT = $("#" + GRASP.config.matrixContainer);
        MATRIX_ELEMENT.html("");

        MATRIXHEADER_ELEMENT.css("top", parseInt(GRID_ELEMENT.offset().top + (GRID_ROWS * 36)) + "px");
        MATRIX_ELEMENT.css("top", parseInt(MATRIXHEADER_ELEMENT.offset().top + MATRIXHEADER_ELEMENT.height()) + "px");

        var cellSize = Math.ceil((GRID_ROWS * 36) / MATRIX_ROWS);
        var coord;

        for (var i=1;i<=MATRIX_ROWS;i++){
            for (var j=1;j<=MATRIX_COLS;j++){
                coord = "" + i + "," + j;
                $(document.createElement("div"))
                    .addClass("autocorrMatrixCellWrapper")
                    .attr("alt", coord)
                    .css("left", parseInt((j-1) * cellSize, 10) + "px")
                    .css("top", parseInt((i-1) * cellSize, 10) + "px")
                    .data("row", i).data("col", j)
                    .appendTo("#"+GRASP.config.matrixContainer)
                    .on("mouseenter", {isMatrix: true}, cellMouseEnter)
                    .on("mouseleave", cellMouseLeave);

                $(document.createElement("div"))
                    .addClass("autocorrMatrixCell autocorrMatrixCellUnselected")
                    .attr("alt", coord)
                    .css("left", parseInt((j-1) * cellSize, 10) + "px")
                    .css("top", parseInt((i-1) * cellSize, 10) + "px")
                    .appendTo("#"+GRASP.config.matrixContainer);
            }
        }

        MATRIX_ELEMENT.height(36 * GRID_ROWS);
        MATRIX_ELEMENT.width(36 * GRID_COLS);
    }

    function cellClick(){
        var cell = $(this).next();

        if(cell.text() == "0"){
            cell.text("1");
        } else {
            cell.text("0");
        }
    }

    function cellMouseEnter(e){
        var i = $(this).data("row");
        var j = $(this).data("col");

        var x = e.data.isMatrix ? Math.ceil((GRID_ROWS * 36) / MATRIX_ROWS) : 36;

        var div = $(document.createElement("div"))
            .addClass("cellCoordinates cellCoordText")
            .css("left", parseInt((j-1) * x, 10) + "px")
            .css("top", parseInt((i-1) * x, 10) + "px")
            .text(i + ", " + j);

        $(this).before(div);
    }

    function cellMouseLeave(){
        $(this).prev().remove();
    }

}(window.GRASP = window.GRASP || {}, jQuery));

$(document).ready(function(){
    GRASP.start();
});
```

CSS:

```
.gridContainer {
/*  width: inherit; */
/*  float: left; */
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    display: block;
    background: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.cell {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;

/*
    font-size: 16pt;
*/
    font-size: x-large;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #888888;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 2em;
/*  padding-top: 0.25em; */
}

.cellSelected {
    background: #00CCFF;
}

.cellUnselected {
    background: none;
}

.cellCoordinates {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    position: absolute;
    background: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
.autocorrMatrixContainer {
    position: absolute;
/*    float: left; */
/*    bottom: 0px; */
    display: block;
    background: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.autocorrMatrixCell {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    font-size: xx-small;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 2em;
/*  padding-top: 0.25em; */
}

.autocorrMatrixCellWrapper {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    background: none;
    z-index: 2;
    border-style: solid outset;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    font-size: x-small;
}

.autocorrMatrixCellCoordText {
    font-size: xx-small;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    color: #444444;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.cellWrapper {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    position: absolute;
    background: none;
    z-index: 2;
    border-style: solid outset;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    font-size: normal;
}

.cellCoordText {
    font-size: x-small;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    color: #444444;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a table for this?

Comment: This would be more suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should have the code in your question; not in a thirdparty link.

Comment: No it could be done in a table, but my thinking is, how I would make the text inside the td and the coordinates to not interfere with the javascript click event. Using the div the wrapper is on top of the other two divs, how can this be implemented in the table?

Comment: I don't get it the code is in the question.. Is there a better way to write the HTML to make the browser not freeze ?

Comment: @vicgonzalez25 There's a lot of code in that JSFiddle that's not in the question; are you saying that you don't need *any* of that code to reproduce your issue? It seems like it's fundamental to the problem.

Comment: Is the browser freeze due to complex HTML layout, or the weight of the JavaScript listeners? Turn off JS in your browser and refresh to answer that question if you need to. I've voted to re-open, but I agree that if this is primarily a JS problem, you should present the problematic JS inside the question. Thus, if that link breaks, the question then does not become useless.

Comment: (On one of your previous questions, a comment said: "Please include relevant code in your question -- not just a link to it").

Comment: As the answer has borne out; your issue can't be reproduced with the code you've provided in the question; please include *all relevant code* from the JS Fiddle.  If I create an HTML page with the grid you show with just HTML, I don't see a problem.

Comment: Ok @GeorgeStocker I added all the code necessary to reproduce the problem. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You  are doing following:

- creating three `divs` per cell,
- creating three handlers per `div` (`onclick`, `onmouseenter`/`onmouceleave`).
  That's loads browser a lot.

You can dramatically decrease the load by doing following:

1. create two `divs` per cell: one with coords (hidden by default), the second with the value;
2. attach event handlers not for each **div** but for the **whole table**;
3. the event handler should rely on `event.target` - it will contain the value and it's neighbor will contain the coords;
4. event handlers should do what they are actually doing in you code but be applicable to the target divs.

One point to handle with: there will be no `onmouseleave` for each particular div; you should run something like `leave(prevDiv)` after `event.target` has been changed (considering you store the `prevDiv` at the end of the event handler).

Good luck with refactoring!

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, are you suggesting to create a table and in every td put two divs (one for the coordinates and the other for the value) and put the event handler to the table and use event.target to get the values and coordinates ? Am I going in the same track as you ? Thanks

Comment: @vicgonzalez25
yes, you are. Actually, either the <table><tr><td> or the <div> layout - it does not matter. The main point is: assigning *one event handler* to the whole table decreases the browser load in comparison to assigning the event handlers to *each cell*.